# automatic continuous numbering in split lists in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, style

Is there any way that numbering in a split list can continue automatically? Because when I apply the style to a subtitle I always have to right click it and choose the option "continue numbering"
Example

```
1.1 subtitle
blabalbalablabla (many paragraphs)
1.2 subtitle (but if i apply the style list show 1.1, i must choose the option "continue numbering" to convert to "1.2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Continue Numbering* is actually part of the *Paragraph Style*.

When you apply *Continue Numbering*, notice that a `+` is added after the name of the *Paragraph Style*. It is seen as an *Override*.

[image]

So you could just hit the *Create new style* button in the bottom of the *Paragraph Styles* panel to create a new style based on the numbering style, which will continue numbering.

So you have a "mother style" which is only applied when you want numbering to reset and another style which you use all other places.

[image]

This setting is located at *Paragraph Style Options > Bullets and Numbering > Numbering Style > Mode*. The options are *Start At* (followed by a certain number) or *Continue from Previous Number*.

[image]

With multiple levels it can become a little convoluted and multiple styles might be needed. The *Restart Numbers at This Level After* setting can come into play.